# Solution to two equations with three unknowns

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

So I'm a student studying through correspondence and I need some help. This is an assignment question, and I have tried everything I know how, to answer it which has lead me to the conclusion that there is no solution.

Here's the question:

[image]

My Answer: I have tried to solve through elimination as well as reduce it to row echelon form in which i still have more unknowns than solutions... Please Help me! I just want to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I think you misunderstood either the question or the data given... You just have to verify that A and B are verifying the two equations... or not!

Comment: Just plug $(2,-1,0)$ and $(7,-4,-1)$ in your given equations and see if they fit.

Comment: There is a reason why they have written *a* solution of the system rather *the* solution of the system

Answer (score 2):

The task does not state that you have to solve the equations, but rather verify. So you just have to 'plug' the points into your system of equations and see if they are satisfied.

Hint: If I calculated correctly $A$ is a solution while $B$ is not.

Comment: Oh yes I see, thanks everyone for your help, I completely misread the question! Just tried plugging it in now, solution x = 2 y = -1 and z = 0 (2, -1, 0) Is a solution and the second is not! Thanks again!